# Targeting data-state to toggle nav headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE**

[image]

I discovered I could toggle the data state on click with

```
$(".list-header").attr("data-state", $(".list-header").hasClass('list-header') ? "hide" : "show");
```

However, when I click the same header I just opened, it doesn't revert back to its original icon or "hide" state.

How can I toggle the current header back to the data-state="hide" state?

```
$('.list-header.major').click(function(){
$(".list-header").attr("data-state", $(".list-header").hasClass('list-header') ? "hide" : "show");
$('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
  $(this).next('div').toggle();
  $('.list-header.major').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

===========================================================================

I need to be able to toggle the "HEADER"'s so that when the subnav is closed for any of them, the header icon is always set to a `+` sign, and has a `data-state=hide`

I found that the state of the headers is always set to active, and that the only way to toggle the `+` or `-` sign is to toggle the `data-state` from `show` to `hide`, which would be based on the state of the `.col-wrapper` classes `style` being either `display:none` or `display: block`.

The question is how to look for the display state of the `.col-wrapper` class and change the `data-state` based on whether the `.list-header` has been clicked or not. I've included screen shots of the states from the fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/3/show/) below.

Essentially, the issue is that the icons aren't toggling back to the plus sign, if the user clicks on another header. This should force any closed list header to go back to the plus sign.

**This is the closed state**
[image]

**This is the open state**
Notice that the `.col-wrapper` class has `display:block` to show the subnav, but the `.list-header` class is still set to `data-state="hide"`, which keeps the header from being toggled back to the correct state.
[image]

I'm trying to target the `data-state` to change to `hide` if the `.col-wrapper` class is `display:none`, by doing something like this:

```
$(".list-header").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).find(".col-wrapper").css("display", "none")){
      force data-state to be hide
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inner">
  <button data-target="#data-nav-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="show" class="list-header major no-style"> <span>HEADER</span> </button>
  <div class="col-wrapper collapse in" id="data-nav-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <li class="list-header mobile"><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">head</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="list-header desktop"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="mobile chevron-right" data-target="#data-inner-0-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-state="hide">
          <button class="no-style sub-header">This should toggle the ul links</button>
        </li>

        <ul class="inner collapse" id="data-inner-0-0">
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.list-header.major').next('div').toggle();
    $('.list-header.major').click(function(){
    $('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
      $(this).next('div').toggle();
      $('.list-header').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });

$('.mobile').next('ul').toggle();
$('.mobile').click(function() {
  $('.mobile').next('ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
  $('.mobile button').removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')) {
      $(this).find('button').addClass('active');
  }
  return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
 button.list-header.major {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    color: $purple;
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
  }

  &:before {
    content: "\E145"; <--THIS IS A PLUS SIGN
  }

  &:after {
    content: "\E15B"; <--THIS IS A MINUS SIGN
  }
}
.sub-header:after{
      content: " >";
      font-family: 'Material Icons';
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(0);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $white;
      position: relative;
      top: 8px;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .sub-header.active:after{
      content: " v";
      color: red;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(8deg);
      font-size: 26px;
      color: $neon-green;
      transition: transform .3s;
    }
```

**UPDATE WITH SCREENSHOT AND MORE DETAIL**

The top navigation should have a `+` icon, not `-`. Here you can see the second Header is opened and has the correct `-`, while the Header above it still has the `-`, although the contents `col-wrapper` has collapsed below it:

[image: First header should have + instead of -]

Comment: You could use $elem.attr("data-state") to get the value and .attr("data-state", newValue) to set the new one.

Comment: @JakubRożek - could you provide an example?

Comment: $("button.list-header").attr("data-state") and $("button.list-header")..attr("data-state", "show"); it this clear?

Comment: I'm trying to set it so that when the user clicks another `list-header`, the previously opened one should toggle back to it's original state. I tried this: `if($(".col-wrapper").css("display") == "none")){
 $(".list-header").attr("data-state", "hide");
}`, but is giving me the error "unexpected token"

So if `col-wrapper` is display:none, the `list-header` should have a data-state = hide

Comment: if ($(this).find(".col-wrapper").css("display") == "none") { 
$(this).attr("data-state", "hide"); 
} should fix your error.

Comment: Hmm, this still isn't hitting the previously opened list header using: `$(".list-header").on('click', function(){
 if ($(this).find(".col-wrapper").css("display") == "none") { $(this).attr("data-state", "hide"); } 
});`

Comment: @JakubRożek - I've added a screenshot of the issue and some more detail. Hopefully this helps clarify what's happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110574/discussion-between-jakub-rozek-and-user3438917).

Comment: I have managed to get the previous `list-header` to toggle back with this: `$(".list-header).attr("data-state", $(".list-header").hasClass("list-header") ? "hide" : "show");`, so now I just need to get the list header that was clicked to go back to its previous state when clicked again. Ideas?

Comment: Please, continue the discussion in the chat. As soon as we find out the solution, we will post the final result here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed code together with the author of question. Should work as expected.

```
$('.list-header.major').click(function(){
if (current !== this)
    $(current).attr('data-state', 'hide');
$(this).attr("data-state", $(this).attr('data-state') === 'hide' ? "hide" : "show");
current = this;
$('.list-header.major').next('div').slideUp();
  $(this).next('div').toggle();
  $('.list-header.major').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

Here is it the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bu35uLn/13)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Much appreciated!